# How to remove NUMIX file icons from Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, icons, desktop-icons

I downloaded Numix Project W10, changed my folder icons. But then I wanted to go back to my default icon settings. So I removed the downloaded folder, deleted "Local Disk C > Windows > System 32 > Iconcache" file & restarted my computer.

But the numix icons didn't go away and the iconcache file renewed after restarting. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

- Right click on your desktop and open Personalization
- In the Themes tab click on Desktop icon settings and Restore Default

[image]